# Typescript, require module as class

Tags: javascript, typescript, amd

I'm using an existing js library that uses AMD modules in my typescript code. I want to use a Javascript class as the base for my Typescript class. This is what I'm trying to do:

**famous.js**

```
define('famous/core/View',['require','exports','module'],function(require, exports, module) {

    function View() {
        ...
    }

    ...

    module.exports = View;
});
```

**View.d.ts**

declare module "famous/core/View" {

}

**AppView.ts**

import View = require('famous/core/View');

class AppView extends View {

}

export = AppView;

But it says "Cannot find name 'View'". I suppose it's logical it doesn't work since a module is not a class, but I don't know another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a class and use [`export =`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#modules-export-) in View.d.ts. For example:

```
declare module "famous/core/View" {
   class View {
      // TODO define members of View
   }
   export = View;
}
```

Comment: Awesome that works. I expected that when I declare a class in the module I would need to use it like this: import View = require('famous/core/View'); var view = new View.View(); . But it doesnt, it works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On further analysis it seems like purely a require configuration problem. It shouldn't have anything to do with `class` vs `module`. Are you sure your paths are correct and you have a `config.ts` require configuration file?

Comment: The js code is part of the library I'm using. That's beyond my control